How to assign color to a Table cell in Pine Script
The table.cell_set_text(table_id, column, row, text) command does not contain the color attribute.
How can I assign color, text_color, text_size and other different attributes to a table cell?

Either you look into the Pine Script language reference for the table cell function(s) and how to change attributes here: Link
Or you can use the Pine Script editor´s hints during coding. When you write table. the editor will show you all available choices resp. functions...

So, depending on what you want to color, you either need table.cell_set_bgcolor() or table.cell_set_text_color().

I could resolve the issue on my own. The reason to use this syntax is to get the real time data. However, thank you for sparing your valuable time. I post my answer also. I checked in the morning to witness the result after market is opened. Purpose did not serve to get the real time data. Would you please help on the issue?

table.cell_set_text(Table_Def, column = 30, row = 4, text = str.tostring(cumdelta[0]))
table.cell_set_text_color(Table_Def, column = 30, row = 4, text_color = color.black)
table.cell_set_text_size(Table_Def, column = 30, row = 4, text_size = size.auto)
table.cell_set_text_halign(Table_Def, column = 30, row = 4, text_halign = text.align_right)

table.cell_set_bgcolor(Table_Def, column = 30, row = 4, bgcolor = cumdelta[0] > 0 and cumdelta[0] > cumdelta[1] * 1.06 ? color.new(color.green, 0) : cumdelta[0] > 0 and cumdelta[0] > cumdelta[1] * 1.03 ? color.new(color.green, 40) : cumdelta[0] > 0 ? color.new(color.green, 80) : cumdelta[0] < 0 and cumdelta[0] < cumdelta[1] * 1.06 ? color.new(color.red, 0) : cumdelta[0] < 0 and cumdelta[0] < cumdelta[1] * 1.03 ? color.new(color.red, 50) : color.new(color.red, 80))
